# SQL query for finding percentage of new records in a table

Tags: sql, database, hiveql

I have two tables `Table1` and `Table2`.

Each of these tables have columns `Column1, Column2`.

I need to **find percentage of new Column1 in Table1 group by Column2.**

> 1) Count of New Records in Column1 = Count of (Distinct Column1
>   present in Table1 and not in Table2).
>
> 2) Count of distinct Column1 in TableOne
>
> Percentage = (1 / 2) * 100.

**What I tried is**

```
 select count(distinct column1) 
    from TableOne left outer join TableTwo on   
                  (tableone.column1=tabletwo.column2) 
    where TableTwo.column1 is null.
```

And this:

```
select count(distinct column1) from tableone.
```

**Now how to combine both in a single query and do group by column2.**

Answer (score 0):

Quick way to do it is:

```
select ((countA/countB)*100) as Percentage (
         select count(distinct column1) as countA, 
                (select count(distinct column1) from tableone) as countB
            from TableOne left outer join TableTwo on   
                          (tableone.column1=tabletwo.column2) 
            where TableTwo.column1 is null) as X
from X
```

For grouping by column2, you just have to add it to the query. But need to know by which column2 you want to group it.

If you need any cross reference in between tables (1 & 2) It'll be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Having two select commands separated by comma is throwing error it seems in HIVE. the error thrown is "cannot recognize input near 'select' 'count' '(' in expression specification".

Comment: It was just SQL general code idea of structure. Don't know exactly in HIVE, plus I don't have all your code and tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @COUNT1 INT
DECLARE @COUNT2 INT

SELECT @COUNT1 = COUNT(*) FROM  comparetable
SELECT @COUNT2 = COUNT(*) FROM  comparetable WHERE Description IS NOT NULL


SELECT CAST(CAST(@COUNT2 AS DECIMAL(10,2) )/CAST(@COUNT1 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS PERCENTAGE
```